# No encuentra la librería array en C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, codeblocks, gcc

El problema es que cada vez que intento compilar me salta un fallo de que no encuentra la librería array.

Las únicas dos definiciones que tengo son:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
```

Y el error que aparece siempre es (en el caso de Eclipse):

```
....cpp:2:17: array: No such file or directory
```

He probado con Eclise, CodeBlocks y Visual Studio Code. Todos usando el unico compilador que tengo, MinGW. De hecho he reinstalado MinGW, desconozco la versión exacta que tengo.
Desde ventana de comandos obtengo:

```
gcc --version 
gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
```

Y desde el programa MinGW Instalation Manager:
[image: Captura MinGW IM]

Y no consigo hacer que compile y funcione.
Sé que existen los arrays predefinidos en C++ pero por exigencia debo usar los de la libreria array haciendo uso de typedef...

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No tengo muy claro si estás usando la versión `3.4.5` o la `6.3.0` del compilador `g++`. Intenta compilar con `g++ -std=c++11` y nos cuentas.